# Locate a file anywhere on the hard drive and transfer it to a different folder

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create an app to transfer any files with a certain name a different folder. So far, I have the following:

```
tell application "Finder"
move (every item of (get path to home folder) whose name is "extended image name.jpg") to ((get path to home folder) & "Pictures" as string)
end tell
```

While this doesn't return any errors, it doesn't do what I want it to either. I am also aware that this only searches the home folder, so if there is any way to do a broader search of the whole drive without having to enter a username, that would be great (I want this to be able to run on more computers than one without them having to edit the script.)

-Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but that line of _code_ can be written as: `move (every item of (path to home folder) whose name is "extended image name.jpg") to path to pictures folder`

Comment: @user3439894 even `(path to home folder)` can be replaced with `home`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code considers only files in the home folder but not in its subfolders, to consider all subfolders you have to add `entire contents`

```
tell application "Finder"
    move (every item of entire contents of home whose name is "extended image name.jpg") to folder "Pictures" of home
end tell
```

But be aware that `entire contents` is extremely slow. The shell command `find` or a spotlight search with `mdfind` is much faster for example

```
set homeFolder to POSIX path of (path to home folder)
set picturesFolder to POSIX path of (path to pictures folder)
do shell script "mdfind -onlyin " & quoted form of homeFolder & " -0 'kMDItemDisplayName = \"extended image name.jpg\"' | xargs -0 -J {} mv {} " & quoted form of picturesFolder
```

## **Important Note**:

As you are moving multiple files with the same name the Finder version will ask for overwriting and the shell version will overwrite all files with the same name.

Comment: Great! That worked perfectly. I just changed home folder to startup disk and mv (move) to cp (copy). -Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Finder to search, if your folder contains only few hundreds files that's OK. But if you want to search in a folder containing thousands of files, Finder will take too long. In this case, it is better to use the shell command 'find' which is much faster.

Syntax of find command is : find directory/ -name target_file_name

Even more, you can chain that command with -exec fonction which will used result of the find to do something: in your case to copy files found in Pictures folder.

In -exec command the {} means the file found. The shell copy command is cp.

This ends with : find /Users/myUserName/ -name 'extended image name.jpg' -exec cp {} \;

(note: the \; tells the system that's the end of the -exec command)

Overall you can run this command in Applescript via do shell script :

```
set Source to POSIX path of (path to home folder)
set Dest to POSIX path of (path to pictures folder)
set TargetName to "extended image name.jpg"
set BackSlash to ASCII character 92
set SemiCol to ASCII character 59

try
    do shell script "find " & Source & " -name " & quoted form of TargetName & " -exec cp {} " & Dest & " " & BackSlash & SemiCol
end try
```

It is much longer than Finder syntax, but also much faster to run !

Notes:

1) the POSIX path convert the Finder path with : to shell path with /

2) the Backslash and SemiCol are set to \ and ; . this is a work around to avoid that Applescript compiler misinterpret the \ during compilation

3) the do shell script is in try/end try block to avoid error. "Find" gives errors when you try to access to files without permission. Such errors will be ignored.

4) with this method, you can replace Source by "/". Doing so, the find will search in all directories of the main drive (it may take some time !). If you want to search for all users, set Source to "/Users/"